# How to retrieve Stripe's Connect authorization code in react-native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup oAuth for Stripe's Connect (Standard). In their setup documentation they say:

> Step 1: Create the OAuth link To get started with your integration,
>   Your client_id, a unique identifier for your platform, generated by Stripe
>   Your redirect_uri, a page on your website to which the user is
>   redirected after connecting their account (or failing to, should that
>   be the case), set by you
>
> Step 3: User is redirected back to your site After the user connects
>   their existing or newly created account to your platform, they are
>   redirected back to your site, to the URL established as your
>   platform’s redirect_uri. For successful connections, we’ll pass along
>   in the URL: The scope granted The state value, if provided An
>   authorization code. The authorization code is short-lived, and can be
>   used only once, in the POST request described in the next step.

The way I've implemented this is by sending the user to a React-Native WebView, and because this is a mobile application, a `redirect_uri` is not an option.

The problem is, I cant simply make a POST request to a url. there are user actions that must be taken inside of stripe, and ultimately stripe sends an authorization code to a redirect url.

So How can I obtain the authorization code that stripe doles out inside the WebView authorization process so I can finish the Stripe Connect user creation process?

Comment: The OAuth flow requires redirecting to an http or https page, so you'd need to redirect out to a hosted page somewhere and then from your hosted page redirect back to a deeplink in the application. The OAuth flow requires a server call at some point because to exchange for the token, you must use a secret key which cannot ship in the mobile bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLoadStart for WebView. Just check if the url from the synthetic event is what you specified in your stripe settings and handle accordingly.

```
onLoadStart={(syntheticEvent) => {
    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
    if(nativeEvent.url.startsWith("YOUR_REDIRECT_URL"){
        // your logic here
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps**

**step 1** : login in mediator strip account, now open new tab and paste below url in new window and replace client id **"ca_****"** with the account which you want to connect with mediator account ( client id ), and hit the url

```
    https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_************************&scope=read_write
```

**step 2** : now press connect button and find the code from new url like
https://connect.stripe.com/connect/default/oauth/test?scope=read_write&code=**ac_**************************